# LAN. не работает обращение одного пк к другому по внешнему IP

Tags: router, lan, static-ip

Есть *пк А* и *пк Б* обьединеные в сеть через маршрутизатор, статический IP, проброшенные порты 80 и 8080 на пк А
Извне локальной сети обращение по статическому IP работает корректно (ведет на *пк А*)
Но если обратится по внешнему IP внутри сети - не работает
Подскажите пожалуйста как настроить так, чтобы *пк Б* смог обращаться к *пк А* по внешнему IP (или по домену)

Comment: Попробуйте создать правило маскарадинга на интерфейсе от ПК-Б с пробросом портов на ПК-А по адресу назначения, равному внешнему адресу ПК-А... вдруг возможно? хотя мне сомнительно, что он будет маскарадить свой локальный адрес.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, включив на роутере NAT loopback